# Why has .fadeTo().each() stopped working?

Tags: jquery

My Wordpress website has a loading animation that hides the content when the page loads then displays it item by item for any element that has the class "typewrite".

At least it did when I made the site but it has stopped working at some point in the last year or two. I'm viewing it in Chrome. It seems like some of the elements show for a brief period then hide before animating in as they should.

You can see the problem at http://www.edwinbradford.com/portfolio. The Homepage, Portfolio and About sections all have the problem and all use the same animation script.

Can anyone see what the error is and explain why it's now behaving differently though nothing has been changed?

```
jQuery('.typewrite').fadeTo(0, 0).each(function(index){
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery(self).fadeTo(250, 1);
            }, index * 100);
});
```

Comment: I see no obvious issues with those pages. Can you give some more details about exactly what the problem is.

Comment: What's the point of `.fadeTo(0, 0)`?

Comment: @jfriend00, think at one point jQuery's animation and show/hide functions had issues if the elements had css rules for them effecting `display` and `opacity` but that has long since been solved. It is also that that call that is probably causing the issue. He shoudl try removing it and then setting up the initial props for `.typewrite` in CSS (presuambly `display:none; opacity:0;`).

Comment: @Rory, sorry if my post was vague. The fault can be seen most clearly on the About page. When the page loads the Wordpress posts should not be visible before they animate in. However several of the posts display, then hide and animate in.

Comment: @prodigitalson This solved it thanks but I'm unable to mark your solution as correct as it's a comment. My CSS had no style for `.typewrite` so I added `opacity: 0` which solved it instantly. When I re-read your comment afterwards I realized it was what you suggested and also that I don't need `.fadeTo(0,0)` anymore.

Comment: @edwinbradford: Added as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the initial `.fadeTo()` call. Hacks like this were common for older versions of jQuery if i remember correctly because for the hide/show/animation related functions. The problem was if the initial properties were set in a `style` tag or in an external sheet the effects did not work properly; You had to set them directly on the `style` attribute of the element which was less than ideal, so a lot of times you would set them from JS either by calling the function you were going to run to set the elements to the initial state or by using `.css()` to do it.

This issue has long since been solved so the proper change here is to remove that initial `.fadeTo()` and just set up the initial state of the elements in CSS. Presumably you want to do both the `display` and `opacity` properties:

```
.typewrite {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And then your modified JS would be:

```
    jQuery('.typewrite').each(function(index){
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery(self).fadeTo(250, 1);
        }, index * 100);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I did and it worked straight away. I couldn't understand why it stopped working but you explained the context very well and saved me a lot of time in the process. Very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this:

```
jQuery('.typewrite').css('opacity', 0).each(function(index, element){
    jQuery(element).delay(index * 100).fadeTo(250, 1);
});
```

This initializes the initial opacity to `0`, then cycles through each `.typewrite` element and sets a variable timing before starting a short `fade()`.

Comment: Yes . Simpler, more efficient Answer. Though why was initial `js` at OP doing what it was doing `jQuery('.typewrite').fadeTo(0, 0).each` ?

Comment: @guest271314 - I don't know exactly why the OP's answer wasn't working.  If jQuery was queueing the `fadeTo()` operation and actually doing an async animation, then it could have conflicted with the initialization of the `.fadeTo()`.  I removed any of those possible ambiguities.  When, in doubt, I first remove any possible oddities.

Comment: The `$` is `undefined` at the page , `jQuery(element)` appear to return expected results.

Comment: @guest271314 - Changed from `$` to `jQuery`.  Is there a reason you're operating without the `$` symbol defined?

Comment: OP may not "see" that second sentence , above, appear to be directed at "them" ?

Comment: @guest271314 - no it was directed at you because you posted about it.  I've already changed the answer, no need for the OP to see the comment.

Comment: Not certain ? Did not compose page . Navigated to page, tried `js` at `console`. Was attempting to "help" convey "best", "most helpful" Answer for OP / SO :)

Comment: @jfriend00 Many thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try but for some reason it didn't seem to solve it. The problem is now resolved, please see my comment above. I'm at a loss to explain why it worked previously then stopped since but I think the current solution is more robust. Thanks again for the reply.